# Index out of range error in swift 3.0

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift3

```
func loadMoreData(lBound: Int, uBound: Int){

    for i in lBound...uBound{
        tempArray.append(arrayDealPage[i])
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()+0.25, execute:{
        self.dealsTable.reloadData()
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if arrayDealPage.count != tempArray.count
    {
        let lastItem = tempArray.count - 1
        if indexPath.row == lastItem{

            loadMoreData(lBound: tempArray.count, uBound:(tempArray.count-1)+20)

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting 195 data from array of images i want to show only 20 at a time then scroll add another 20. Above code is working fine but when i reaches about 181 or 182 cell it crashes index out of range error.195 array count can be increase in future how to resolve index out of range error.Could someone help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't check if uBound index is outside of the arrayDealPage array bounds.
try this:

```
func loadMoreData(lBound: Int, uBound: Int){
    // checkeduBound variable never go outside the array bounds
    var checkeduBound = uBound
    if uBound >= arrayDealPage.count {
        checkeduBound = arrayDealPage.count-1
    }

    //edited
    if lBound > checkeduBound { return }

    //use new checkeduBound here
    for i in lBound...checkeduBound{
        tempArray.append(arrayDealPage[i])
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()+0.25, execute:{
        self.dealsTable.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: bro will this code work for me for 195 data or will be work for more data als means condition @Jaba Odishelashvili

Comment: yes it should work in every case, even array become larger. Does it have again crash?

Comment: one crash happed fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound

Comment: for i in lBound...checkeduBound{
            tempArray.append(arrayDealPage[i])
        }


app is crashing here if while calling api array count is empty

Comment: help me @Jaba Odishelashvili

Comment: can you post crash log?

Comment: fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound

Comment: try to add this line before foreach loop 
if lBound > checkeduBound { return }

Comment: but there will be better approach to control your data... you can debug it line by line and find problem in detail

Comment: do u have skype id

Comment: i think my issue is resolved now....but before accepting answer could u explain the code it will help me thanks in advance